# Swift Debugger: how to disable it in order to run app?

Tags: ios, debugging, swift

I'm new to programming and have encountered an extremely frustrating problem with Swift in Xcode- the debugger is preventing me from running my app in the simulator. When I click "run", I get a green bar with a message in it and no matter how many times I tell the debugger to "continue", the simulator remains black and the green bar does not move from that one specific line of code.

On the "class AppDelegate" line in my app delegate I get the message: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

What is the point of the debugger here? It really doesn't seem to be helping at all, just preventing me from seeing my code running. How can I fix this?
My code:

```
//Initializing all imgs as variables:


@IBOutlet var circle1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle3: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle4: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle5: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle6: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle7: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle8: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var circle9: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var circleBtn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var circleBtn9: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var resetBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var ResultsLabel: UILabel!

//Creating variables:

var plays = Dictionary<Int,Int>()
var done = false
var aiDeciding = false

//Function that says what to do if a UIButton is clicked:

@IBAction func UIbuttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    ResultsLabel.hidden = true
    if !plays[sender.tag] && !aiDeciding && !done {
    setImgforCircle(sender.tag, player:1)

    }

//Executing these functions:

    checkforWin()
    aiTurn()

}

//Function that says sets an X or O in the proper circle depending on player:

func setImgforCircle(spot:Int, player:Int) {
    var playerMark = player == 1 ? "Red_x" : "Red_o"
    plays[spot] = player
    switch spot {
    case 1:
        circle1.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 2:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 3:
        circle3.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 4:
        circle4.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 5:
        circle5.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 6:
        circle6.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 7:
        circle7.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 8:
        circle8.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    case 9:
        circle9.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)

    default:
        circle2.image = UIImage(named: playerMark)
    }

}

//Function that sees if certain paths of circles have the same mark

func checkforWin() {
var whoWon = ["Lost":0, "Won":1]
    for (key,value) in whoWon {
        if ((plays[1] == value && plays[2] == value && plays[3] == value) || //across top row
        (plays[4] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[6] == value) || //across middle row
        (plays[7] == value && plays[8] == value && plays[9] == value) || //across bottom row
        (plays[1] == value && plays[4] == value && plays[7] == value) || //down left column
        (plays[2] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[8] == value) || //down middle column
        (plays[3] == value && plays[6] == value && plays[9] == value) || //down right column
        (plays[1] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[9] == value) || //diagonal going right
        (plays[7] == value && plays[5] == value && plays[3] == value)) { //diagonal going left

            ResultsLabel.hidden = false
            ResultsLabel.text = "You \(key)!"
            done = true
        }

    }

}
func aiTurn() {

}

func reset() {
    plays = [:]
    circle1.image = nil
    circle2.image = nil
    circle3.image = nil
    circle4.image = nil
    circle5.image = nil
    circle6.image = nil
    circle7.image = nil
    circle8.image = nil
    circle9.image = nil
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: "green bar with a message"? what message? and it is more likely your code crashed so it can't move on

Comment: On the "class AppDelegate" line in my app delegate I get the message: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: so your app crashed. now you need to learn how to use debugger to fix it

Comment: How do I do that?? Please help me, I have no idea how to use this. If it's crashing, why isn't it giving me any errors?

Comment: Start by adding exception breakpoints: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions and then show us the piece of code that is causing the problem

Comment: @connor I just posted all of my code. It is still drawing a breakpoint on that one line of code in the App Delegate, and I never touched that line of code (it comes pre written by apple).

Comment: If you're new to programming, it may be best to start with a language and development environment that's not still in beta. It's going to be tough to tell the difference between your own mistakes and problems with the language and tools. Heck, I've been programming for 30 years and it's still tripping me up sometimes. Perhaps start with learning something that's a bit more mature and well-known.

Comment: Post the debugger output if you want help with solving it.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going though [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1) guide. It helps quite a bit to debug. When you look at the debugger, you can usually find the source of your problem. Signal SIGABRT is usually the easiest to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem myself. Chances are you deleted something in your ViewController file but did not delete the connection between the storyboard and the file. Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781565/trouble-debugging-uibutton/here) for more info on how I fixed the problem.

Hope this can help you if you are still having problems.