# Trouble Debugging UIButton

Tags: debugging, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I am having some trouble with debugging a UIButton. There is an error I don't know how to fix. I almost certain it is within this code somewhere. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func checkButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if (flashButton.hidden == true){
        flashButton.hidden == false
        flashingImageView.hidden == true
    }else if (flashButton.hidden == false)
    {
        flashButton.hidden == true
        flashingImageView.hidden == false
    }
    if ( "\(randomImageGeneratorNumber)" == "\(currentCountLabel.text)"){

        currentAmountCorrect + currentAmountCorrect + 1
        amountCorrectLabel.text = "\(currentAmountCorrect)"
    }else{
        currentAmountIncorrect = currentAmountIncorrect + 1
        amountIncorrectLabel.text = "\(currentAmountIncorrect)"
    }

    if (currentCountLabel.text == "0"){

      let alert = UIAlertView()
      alert.title = "Alert"
      alert.message = "You must type in an answer in order to check it"
      alert.addButtonWithTitle("Understood")
      alert.show()

    }

    currentCount *= 0
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
```

}

The error in the debugger output says:
 '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key CheckButton.'

I am not sure how to fix this. Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check if your button is correctly connected in the Interface Builder.

Comment: It is Correctly connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you accidentally create an `@IBOutlet` to your button, and then just delete the `IBOutlet` from the code.  In this situation, the Storyboard still tries to hook up the button to the `@IBOutlet` property in your `ViewController`, but it fails because the `IBOutlet` in the code is gone.  If this is indeed what you did, to fix it:

1. <kbd>Control</kbd>-click on the button in the Storyboard.
2. From the list that pops up, scroll down to the *Referencing Outlets* section at the bottom.

   [image]
3. There, if you see an outlet listed, click on the `x` next to the `ViewController` to delete this outlet.

Comment: Do I then just reconnect the button or do I leave as is after I delete the outlet?

Comment: In the pop up, is Touch Up Inside connected to your button like in my picture?  If not, then yes, just control drag from your button to your checkButton routine.

Comment: It is connected the same way as your picture.

Comment: If you get rid the the `CheckButton` outlet under the `Referencing Outlets` section, your button should then work without crashing.

Comment: It still has the same error in the debugger when I run it.

Comment: Is `Touch Up Inside` the only connection you see when you control click on your button?

Comment: If you're still having a problem with this, I would suggest deleting the button from the Storyboard and then making sure you can build without errors.  Then, add the button back to the Storyboard, then drag from the circle to the left of your `checkButton` routine to the button in the Storyboard to set up the connection.

Comment: Control click on your button and look at the pop up.  How does it compare to the one I posted?

Comment: I already deleted the referencing outlet like you said but the debugger has the same output as before

Comment: Nevermind. I ran the app again on the Simulator and it work fine. Thanks